# Using Allegro 5 library with Jetbrains CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, allegro, allegro5

I am using CLion on Windows with MinGW (gcc/g++). I spend few hours working out why I cannot compile simple program, because I have issues with linking everything.

I tried to combine all found solutions on the Internet, applied changes which helped other people.. Still I am leaving with problems.

Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "allegro5/allegro.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

    al_init();
    return 0;
}
```

And CmakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(allegro/lib)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(allegro/include)
add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(untitled  allegro_acodec
        allegro_audio
        allegro_color
        allegro_dialog
        allegro_image
        allegro_main
        allegro_memfile
        allegro_physfs
        allegro_primitives
        allegro_ttf
        allegro_font
        allegro)


file(GLOB LIBRARIES "allegro/lib/*.dll.a")
message("LIBRARIES = ${LIBRARIES}")

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(untitled  ${LIBRARIES})
```

That is what build process pops out:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.3.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Adrian\CLionProjects\untitled\cmake-build-debug --target untitled -- -j 8
-- Configuring done

LIBRARIES = C:/Users/Adrian/CLionProjects/untitled/allegro/lib/liballegro-debug.dll.a;C:/Users/Adrian/CLionProjects/untitled/allegro/lib/liballegro.dll.a;C:/Users/Adrian/CLionProjects/untitled/allegro/lib/liballegro_acodec-debug.dll.a; [... and more....]

-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Adrian/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug

Scanning dependencies of target untitled
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable untitled.exe

CMakeFiles\untitled.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/Adrian/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `al_install_system'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Project structure is:

```
└───untitled
    ├───.idea
    ├───allegro
    │   ├───bin
    │   ├───include
    │   │   └───allegro5
    │   │       ├───inline
    │   │       ├───internal
    │   │       ├───opengl
    │   │       │   └───GLext
    │   │       └───platform
    │   └───lib
    └───cmake-build-debug
        └───CMakeFiles
            ├───3.6.3
            │   ├───CompilerIdC
            │   └───CompilerIdCXX
            ├───arkanoid.dir
            ├───CMakeTmp
            ├───Progress
            └───untitled.dir
```

I have downloaded Allegro 5 x64 version, tried both allegro-mingw-gcc5.3.0-x64-dynamic and static from here: https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/releases

Thank you

Comment: Probably, your MinGW compiler's version is not `5.3.0`. If so, just build Allegro in your MinGW environment.

Comment: I have installed MinGW version 6.2.0 from here and it worked: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

Answer (score -1):

You must use the same version of compiler as was used to build the allegro binaries. Otherwise it just won't work right.